# Proof of dimension formula for sl(3,C) reps

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, representation-theory

this is my first question on the forums, so forgive me if I did something wrong. I have
tried to find an answer in here as well as on the usual places on the internet and was
unsuccessful. So here goes:

I'm trying to prove the formula:
$$
\textrm{dim}_{sl(3,\mathbb{C})}(\left[a,b]\right) = \frac{1}{2}(a+1)(b+1)(a+b+2)
$$
where $\left[ a,b\right]$ are the Dynkin labels of the representation of $\textrm{dim}_{sl(3,\mathbb{C})}$.

I know that the dimension of the representation
is the number of Young tableau fillings of Y with integers $\left\{ 1,2,3\right\}$, where
Y is the Young tableau with row length $\left( r_1,r_2\right)$ (and $a=r_1-r_2$, $b=r_2$).
A filling here is supposed to mean weakly increasing numbers along rows and strictly increasing along columns.

Now I have to show that the above formula follows combinatorically, but I can't see how,
as there seem to be too many dependencies of what numbers I can put where.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I hope it help- Fulton, Harris' book, page 77, Theorem 6.3

Comment: Well, I can kinda see that the formula is contained in the first part of that theorem, but to be honest I do not understand even the complete statement of the theorem (very unfamiliar with the notations, I am not a mathematician). Also the only version I have available is the free google-version one, where the pages containing the proof of that particaluar theorem are omitted. Thanks for the hint though. Do you have any idea how to see the combinatorics oneself? It is just combinatorics, isn't it?

Comment: then try Humphreys (1972, Section 24.3).