# 12 dimensional irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{c})$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I need to know if there are any 12 dimensional irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb{C})$

I roughly understand the general theory of how every finite dimensional representation has a decomposition into weight spaces and so on (Fulton Harris). I am having difficulty in explicitly computing it for this case. Any help or direction (like a procedure to follow) to arrive at the result will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you know what the representations "look like" in the weight spaces? For example, do you know what the fundamental rep and the adjoint rep look like? Also, are you aware that the dimension and weights of a representation are completely determined by the highest weight? And do you know how to compute these weights, given the highest weight?

Comment: There is even a formula for the dimension of an irrep, given in terms of the highest weights: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631654/proof-of-dimension-formula-for-sl3-c-reps.

Comment: Yup! I know all the above! :) But I am not able to understand how to do this for an abstract 12 dimensional space...

Comment: I know this formula... I have done a lot of trial and error but couldn't find any combination of non-negative integers which would yield 12. I am also not able show that there can't be a 12dimensional irreducible representation. I must admit my representation theory is not strong at all.

Comment: But if you know this, then it reduces to a number theory problem: Do there exist non-negative integers $a$, $b$ such that $\frac 1 2 (a + 1)(b+1)(a + b + 2) = 12$?

Comment: I don't understand, how do I decisively show that there exist no such non negative integers? I don't know any number theory that helps here.. :/

Comment: Would you like to start with finding the factors of 24?

Comment: I already said that trial and error doesn't help.. I have already tried decomposing it into factors and trying all possible combinations.

Comment: And my point is that $a + 1$, $b+1$ and $a+ b + 2$ are all positive factors of 24. So $a + 1$, $b + 1$ and $a + b + 2$ must all be contained in the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12, 24\}$.

Comment: That is clear.. Do u see the particular (a,b) such that the equation is satisfied? Because the problem now is to find $x,y \in \{1,2,3,4,6,12,24\}$ such that $(x+y)(xy)=24$ and that is a quadratic polynomial in two variables. And I am still at loss how to do this.

Comment: Well, first of all, since $x + y \geq x$, we must have $x \leq \sqrt{24}$, i.e. $x \in \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$. Same for $y$. So you don't exactly have many cases to check...